# Protractor: Iterating over options works if debugging but doesn't if not

Tags: angularjs, combobox, protractor

I have the following test (for the sake of brievity I've removed the page object):

```
element(by.model("elc.search.placeOfBirth")) //this is a select

element(by.model("elc.search.placeOfBirth")).all(by.tagName("option")).then(function(options) {
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].getText().then(function(text) {
      if(text !== "---") {
        element(by.model("elc.search.placeOfBirth")).sendKeys(text);

        var firstRow = element.all(by.repeater("employee in elc.filtered")).first();
        firstRow.all(by.tagName("td")).then(function(cells) {
          expect(cells[4].getText()).toBe(text);
        });

        var lastRow = element.all(by.repeater("employee in elc.filtered")).last();
        lastRow.all(by.tagName("td")).then(function(cells) {
          expect(cells[4].getText()).toBe(text);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Let me explain what's happening here. I have a table and a select box above it. The table's 5th column is related to the select combobox and the array I use in ng-repeat for the table is filtered by the value in the combobox. What I wanted to do here is to go over the values in the combobox, select a particular value and make sure the table has that value in the first and last row.

If I but `browser.debugger()` in the loop this works and the test passes, however if I don't debug the testing seems to go too fast and my table doesn't get updated quickly enough and the tests fail. I'm guessing this is due to the fact that a promise isn't resolved and the code keeps running, but I'm not sure which promise I'm waiting for, as I've also tried to put a `.then(function() {...}` right after I send the keys to the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `for` loop executes quickly and so the code inside it waiting for promises gets skipped. You can avoid it by executing a function inside the `for` loop. Update your code to do it -

```
var someFunction = function(options, i){
    //Write your code that was inside your for loop
};

element(by.model("elc.search.placeOfBirth")).all(by.tagName("option")).then(function(options) {
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        someFunction(options, i);
    }
});
```

However there's a better solution for this problem. Use the inbuilt loops that protractor has `.each()` or `.map()` to get your job done. Here's how -

```
element(by.model("elc.search.placeOfBirth")).all(by.tagName("option")).each(function(option) {
    option.getText().then(function(text) {
      if(text !== "---") {
        element(by.model("elc.search.placeOfBirth")).sendKeys(text);

        var firstRow = element.all(by.repeater("employee in elc.filtered")).first();
        firstRow.all(by.tagName("td")).then(function(cells) {
          expect(cells[4].getText()).toBe(text);
        });

        var lastRow = element.all(by.repeater("employee in elc.filtered")).last();
        lastRow.all(by.tagName("td")).then(function(cells) {
          expect(cells[4].getText()).toBe(text);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

You may use wait's in between to make sure your DOM is updated before you perform any operation. Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: While it does seem to go slower when I extract it into a separate function my combobox only gets the keys sent the first time this way and ignores the other values (I've added a console.log to make sure the different text values are there). Any idea why the combobox is ignoring further keys sent?

Also, why does the code work when I extract it into a function, what difference does it make?

Comment: from what I can tell, sendkeys when invoked the second time doesn't actually delete the keys that were sent the first time. This causes a problem since I can't clear() the actual select box. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2352164 you have to manually clear a text box or a combo box value. Whenever you input anything new, it adds to existing value. In order to remove the existing data include a `element(by.model("elc.search.placeOfBirth")).clear()` command at the end of the function before entering new data. Hope it helps

Comment: the thing is, it doesn't allow me to clear the select element, it throws an error stating that clear can be called only on text inputs.

Comment: @user2352164 i thought you were trying to clear a combo box. I don't know if you clear a select element. In case of select element all you can do is select the default element using `click()` action, if the default item is enabled to be selected for user. You can get help in stack overflow to click an option on select element. Thanks